# JOIN always the default value, else join the match value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server Query

```
select r.isactive,r.workingyear,r.startperiod,r.endperiod,r.anniversary
from setup_holiday_policy t cross apply
 (select data
  from dbo.Split(t.scheduleapplication, ',')
 ) di cross apply
 (select max(case when did.id = 1 then did.data end) as isactive,
         max(case when did.id = 2 then did.data end) as workingyear,
         max(case when did.id = 3 then did.data end) as anniversary,
         max(case when did.id = 4 then did.data end) as startperiod,
         max(case when did.id = 5 then did.data end) as endperiod
  from dbo.Split(di.data,':') did
 ) r
 WHERE r.workingyear =  @employeeworkingyears
```

The policy table can have a 0 value in the workingyear field. Meaning that when this field has 0 then is the default record I should return.

```
setup_holiday_policy
```

So, if `@employeeworkingyears = 2` and there is **no** `workingyears = 2` in `setup_holiday_policy` I should return the default row that has the 0 value in workingyears field.

This is a sample of the rows returned.

[image]

Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show an example data table and result table?

Comment: If my table matches the where r.workingyear = something then return the record found, else if there is no match I should always return the row that has 0 in the workingyear field.

Comment: Can you please reduce your query to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate your problem - specifically don't copy paste your entire actual query, because 90% of it is noise and irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one row is going to be returned (as suggested by the sample data), you can do this using `top`:

```
select top 1 r.isactive,r.workingyear,r.startperiod,r.endperiod,r.anniversary
from setup_holiday_policy t cross apply
     (select data
      from dbo.Split(t.scheduleapplication, ',')
     ) di cross apply
     (select max(case when did.id = 1 then did.data end) as isactive,
             max(case when did.id = 2 then did.data end) as workingyear,
             max(case when did.id = 3 then did.data end) as anniversary,
             max(case when did.id = 4 then did.data end) as startperiod,
             max(case when did.id = 5 then did.data end) as endperiod
      from dbo.Split(di.data,':') did
     ) r left outer join
     (select @employeeworkingyears as employeeworkingyears
     ) e
     on 
WHERE r.workingyear in (@employeeworkingyears, 0)
order by r.workingyear desc;
```